# Error de indentación

Tags: python

estoy haciendo un ejercicio para entrenar los condicionales y ciclos, y a la hora de ejecutarlo para ver que tal va, este me da unos errores de Indentación, ya lo he revisado y no he podido encontrar el error, me podrían ayudar para saber en que me he equivocado. Los errores me aparecen en la línea 30 y al dar enter al comienzo de la línea 22

```
respuesta=1
print('ESCAPATORIA DE LA PRISION ESPACIAL')

print('''\nTe acabas de escapar de la prision espacial junto a tu companero de celda,
lograron burlar a los guardias, y ahora se dirigen hacia el exterior. Mientras buscan 
la salida se introducen en un cuartel controlado por monstruos alienigenas. Uno 
de estos, ataca a tu companero y se lo lleva de vuelta a su celda. Tu logras pasar 
desaperecibido escondido entre las sombras. Luego de cruzar este cuarto hay un pasillo.
Al final de este hay 2 caminos por los que puedes seguir: Una puerta semi-abierta, 
o una escotilla en el suelo en la cual puedes saltar. \n¿Que opcion eliges?''')

respuesta=int(input('1.-Puerta semi-abierta \n2.-Escotilla en el suelo \n-->'))
while respuesta != 1 and respuesta != 2:
    print('Has ingresado mal la respuesta, vuelve a intentarlo')
    respuesta=int(input('1.-Puerta semi-abierta\n2.-Escotilla en el suelo \n-->'))

if respuesta ==1:
    print('''\nTe has encontrado con un guardia que tiene un gorro vikingo. Puedes hacer 2 
    cosas: Hacerte el dormido, o salir corriendo. \n¿Que opcion eliges?''')
    
    respuesta=int(input('1.-Hacerse el dormido\n2.-Salir Corriendo \n-->'))
    while respuesta != 1 and respuesta != 2:
        print('Has ingresado mal la respuesta, vuelve a intentarlo')
        respuesta=int(input('1.-Hacerse el dormido\n2.-Salir Corriendo \n-->'))

    if respuesta==1:
        print('''\nTe has hecho el dormido. Lamentablemente estos guardias no dejan este cuarto 
        sin vigilar por lo tanto no podras moverte mas de ahi. Has muerto de Hambre. \nFIN DEL JUEGO''')
    else:
        print('mas codigo')

else:
    print('mas codigo')
```

Comment: Que error obtienes ? especifica por favor.

Comment: @Elenasys IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level